# What cryptographic primitives use AES or its Round function?

Tags: aes, algorithm-design

I have found the following two block/stream ciphers or Hash Construction that make use of AES or its round functions

1. [A New 128-bit Key Stream Cipher LEX](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/ciphers/lex/lex.pdf)
2. [3D: A Three-Dimensional Block Cipher](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/128649/files/Nak08.pdf)
3. ALE
4. ASC-1

Which other constructions make direct use of AES round function?

Comment: If im reading the 3D paper correctly, it does not actually use the round function

Comment: There are so many ciphers that use AES (AES-CBC, AES-CTR, AES-GCM, AES-as-used-by-such-option-of-such-program..) that it is pointless to list them. Is the question asking what ciphers make use of the AES round function rather than of AES? Perhaps that could be extended to hashes, MACs, block ciphers.. with:  _What cryptographic algorithms make use of the AES round function rather than of the full AES?_ Or from an implementation perspective: what are other uses of AES(ENC|DEC)[LAST] instructions beyond AES?

Comment: @RichieFrame yes u are right

Comment: The [Whirlpool hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_(cryptography)) is based on AES.

Comment: @fgrieu AES-CBC, AES-CTR etc modes of operation, which can be true in context of any cipher. So at the moment, i am only interested what all ciphers make use of Complete AES block encrypt or AES round function (may be with some little variation too). Like LEX uses Complete AES

Comment: I have 3 ciphers, FIAESTY SHIAESTY and Vertigo, that make direct use of the AES round function. FIAESTY/SHIAESTY were designed in response to a question on this site regarding involutional block ciphers, and Vertigo is a work-in-progress experimental duplexed sponge construction with a large state, overviews of both posted to sci.crypt

Comment: @RI8S: There is a terminology issue. AES is a block cipher; it is not a cipher as usually defined in modern cryptography (or for definitions of a cipher that can include AES, it is not a cipher secure under [CPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack), which is considered a desirable property of a cipher). CBC, CTR are generic methods to build a cipher from a block cipher (_not_ from another cipher!), and AES-CBC, AES-CTR are ciphers. Perhaps your are asking for _block ciphers that use AES or its round function?_

Comment: @RichieFrame can you please provide link to the specifications of your mentioned ciphers?

Comment: The terminology problem is now 80% cleared up by asking "block or stream ciphers". It remains that any stream cipher that uses AES as a black box is bound to be a mode of operation in some sense, just like AES-CTR and AES-CFB are stream ciphers using AES as a black box. Let's say that these two, and their simple variations as used in many programs, are the only modes of operation excluded from the scope, and end up with a well-defined question.

Comment: The basic overviews were posted to the sci.crypt newsgroup, there is no public complete specification for any of them

Comment: @RichieFrame please share details or links.