# Symmetric Crypto Primitives derived from Rijndael Block Cipher

Tags: aes, block-cipher

Rijndael Block Cipher supports multiple block/ key lengths and a subset of these was selected as AES. What other cryptographic primitives are derived from Rijndael or make use of its round function/ design principle (e.g LED Block Cipher, Lex Stream Cipher)? Are there any other possible variants of Rijndael/ AES that have been proposed/ published?

Comment: Ukrainian standards for block encryption ("Kalyna") and hashing ("Kupyna") use Rijndael-like constructs and have a number of optimizations for 64-bit processors.

Comment: There are tons, look at the Caesar competition

Comment: @RichieFrame any info about primitives other than Block Ciphers derived from AES architecture or round functions.

Comment: also see this unanswered question, which is essentially identical to this one: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54599/what-cryptographic-primitives-use-aes-or-its-round-function